# Plotting border dissapears when changing FaceAlpha

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to change the FaceAlpha (make transparent) of my bar plot. If I do like this the right border of the plot dissapears. This is what it looks like of I don't change the FaceAlpha:

```
barplot = bar(xmin:binw:xmax,prob);
```

[image: Not Change Face Alpha]

And if I try to change it, like this:

```
barplot = bar(xmin:binw:xmax,prob);
set(get(barplot,'Child'),'FaceAlpha',0.3)
```

The right border dissapears!

[image: No right border]

Furhtermore, what I really want is to make a bar plot with the 'hist' option. But then it doesn't work to change the FaceAlpha! Like this:

```
barplot = bar(xmin:binw:xmax,prob,'hist');
set(get(barplot,'Child'),'FaceAlpha',0.3) //This row has no effect
```

[image: No FaceAlpha effect]

Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to the dissapearing border here, and it works:

http://www.mathworks.se/support/solutions/en/data/1-5X41G7/index.html

Still the question remains why it's not possible to change the FaceAlpha when using the 'hist' option.